# Как рассмотреть (mesh) частицу со всех сторон в unity?

Tags: unity3d

На сцене имеется mesh частица, я хочу рассмотреть эту частицу с разных сторон, но когда я пытаюсь посмотреть на неё сбоку, то она сама начинает вращаться в ту же сторону, как бы отворачиваясь от меня. Как это исправить?

Comment: Так частицы - это же 2Д картинки. Они будут 2Д картинками с любой стороны, и с любой стороны они будут выглядеть одинаково, как бы поворачиваясь к зрителю лицом.

Comment: Логично. Просто я смотрю видео, где чел может рассмотреть свою частицу с разных ракурсов. Грубо говоря есть система частиц, в которой есть полусфера с наложенной на неё текстурой, и он может эту полусферу с разных сторон рассмотреть. В своем же проекте я не могу этого сделать

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, не без подсказки другого человека, в чем дело.
Renderer - Render alignment - world.